# writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum and enumerate images in the album

Tags: ios, ios6, alassetslibrary, alasset

I'm using `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:` to save an image and it's ok. Then I want an array of assets in the Album.

The first time I refresh my array it doesn't count the new image, while calling it a second time it works fine.
Why? I understand that the `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` start another thread and that the Block is called after the save operation completes, isn't it?

This is the code I use to save the image and refresh my array:

```
[_album refresh];
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image
                             metadata:metadataAsMutable
                      completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                                  if (error) {
                                      NSLog(@"ERROR: the image failed to be written");
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      NSLog(@"PHOTO SAVED - assetURL: %@", assetURL);
                                  }
                                  [_album refresh];
                                  [_album refresh];
                                  [spinner stopAnimating];
                                  [self close];
                              }];
```

This is the `refresh` function:

```
- (void)refresh {
    [_imgAssets removeAllObjects];
    if (_albumGroup) {
        [_albumGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if(result == nil) {
                NSLog(@"done enumerating photos (%d)", [_imgAssets count]);
                return;
            }
            [_imgAssets addObject:result];
            //NSLog(@">> enumerating photos (%d)", [_imgAssets count]);
        }];
    }
}
```

And this is what I obtain:

```
2013-06-04 23:19:07.962 PhotInfo[4835:c07] done enumerating photos (29)
2013-06-04 23:19:08.041 PhotInfo[4835:c07] PHOTO SAVED - assetURL: assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=CDC2E97A-FF47-4A52-99E2-574037155D92&ext=JPG
2013-06-04 23:19:08.042 PhotInfo[4835:c07] done enumerating photos (29)
2013-06-04 23:19:08.044 PhotInfo[4835:c07] done enumerating photos (30)
```

Moreover, if I replace the second of the 3 `refresh` with

```
[_album performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

it may or may not read the added image.

Where is the problem?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Im not sure there is a problem, I think there is just a delay before the image is available. It sure does suck and I've just worked around it with a perform selector. Not that I like it...

Comment: Yes. In facts I've tried with a simple wait, but how much to delay? The problem is I thought the image was immediately available…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved setting an observer on `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification`.